# Make RadCaptcha from Telerik work with Peter's Data Entry Suite button

Tags: asp.net, webforms, telerik, peterblum

```
 <telerik:RadCaptcha ID="RadCaptcha1" runat="server" ValidationGroup="SaveUser"
  ErrorMessage="Please enter a valid code." EnableRefreshImage="true"
  RegisterWithScriptManager="true" IgnoreCase="False" ClientIDMode="AutoID">
 </telerik:RadCaptcha>

<des:Button ID="btnVAMFinish" runat="server" Group="SaveUser"
 CausesValidation="true" ValidationGroup="SaveUser" 
 CommandName="MoveComplete" Text="Finish" />
```

I am using a DES button (Peter Blum's Data Entry Suite) with RadCaptcha on an asp.net webforms page, but it does not validate the RadCaptcha control from Telerik. In code behind, I am always getting PeterBlum.DES.Globals.WebFormDirector.IsValid == true even when I input an incorrect text for RadCaptcha.

**My question**: Is there any way to make RadCaptcha work with a DES button?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to solve this problem. RadCaptcha works seamlessly with Peter's DES button. However, it must be setup correctly independent of whether DES button or regular ASP.Net button is used. So, RadCaptcha is perfectly compatible with DES button.

In my case, there were a couple of ajax postbacks in which the RadCaptcha was not being updated by the ajax response.

So I first wrapped the RadCaptcha in a server-side div, and then included it in the updated list of controls for these ajax postbacks. This solved the problem.

```
<div id="divCaptcha" runat="server" style="text-align: center; margin: auto; "  >

    <telerik:RadCaptcha ID="RadCaptcha1" runat="server" ValidationGroup="SaveUser"
  ErrorMessage="Please enter a valid code." EnableRefreshImage="true"
  RegisterWithScriptManager="true" IgnoreCase="False" ClientIDMode="AutoID">
 </telerik:RadCaptcha>
</div>
```

In Page Load event of asp.net page, I included the following code.

```
RadAjaxManager1.AjaxSettings.AddAjaxSetting(VendorsRadComboBox, divCaptcha)
RadAjaxManager1.AjaxSettings.AddAjaxSetting(categoriesRadTree, divCaptcha)
```